# String to int array

Tags: java, string, int

I have the following code as Strings

```
[444398, 1]
[111099, 0]
[188386, 2]
[149743, 0]
```

and I want to make a two-dimensional array with each number as an int.
For example,

`int[][] temp = new int[4][2]`

I am trying to use

```
String challengetemp = Arrays.toString(Challenge.challenge(players[0], players[1]));
challengeList[i][i] = Integer.parseInt(challengetemp.split("\\|",-1));
```

but for starters, ParseInt is getting a type mismatch and results in an error.

I would need to be able to access the info from the array afterwards as integers

Comment: ``parseInt(String)`` accepts a String as a parameter, not a ``String[]``, which is what the ``split(String, int)`` returns.

Comment: Why are you splitting on `|`? Can we see how your actual input look like? And what is `Challenge`? Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: (I haven't checked these in code yet, but..) splitting on `"[\\[\\]\n]"` should split up your string on the first index, then splitting on `","` should take care of the inner arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
    String string = "[444398, 1]";
    string = string.substring(1, string.length()-1); //Turns it into "444398, 1"
    String[] stringInArray = string.split(", "); // Then makes it ["444398", "1"]

    int[][] temp = new int[4][2];

    temp[0][0] = Integer.parseInt(stringInArray[0]);
    temp[0][1] = Integer.parseInt(stringInArray[1]);
```

You will have to modify it into a loop for doing multiple of course!

Answer (score 2):

And I would utilize [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to do something like this.

```
    String str = "[444398, 1][111099, 0][188386, 2][149743, 0]";

        str = str.replace("[","");
        str = str.replace("]","|");

        int arr[][] = new int[4][2];
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(str,"|");
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            StringTokenizer nextToken = new StringTokenizer(token.nextToken(),",");
         for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
          {
            String tokenValue = nextToken.nextToken();
            if(tokenValue.contains("|"))
            {
                tokenValue.replace("|", "");
            }
            arr[i][j]= Integer.parseInt(tokenValue.trim());
          }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
            }
        };
```

And you would have to modify a little to the loop, so that it would parse as many String to int array as you want.